# Running `system 'rake'` from within a Ruby gem: how to suppress the console output?

Tags: ruby, logging, console, rubygems, rake

I have to run a `system "rake assets:precompile"` from within a Ruby gem.

How can I prevent it from outputting anything to the console? At the moment it's outputting the following:

```
I, [2014-01-19T14:11:19.599828 #76714]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/josh/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/transition/public/assets/application-90b828df450eb4e5dd0b88931da42ead.js
I, [2014-01-19T14:11:19.929472 #76714]  INFO -- : Writing /Users/josh/Documents/Work/MuheimWebdesign/transition/public/assets/application-b1bed1c63f05b07c72f1ac7e31b65551.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the output to [a place nothing ever happens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null):

```
system "rake assets:precompile &> /dev/null"
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the output is still there. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Perfect, it's working now! Can you explain a bit more what the `&` is doing? Thank you.

Comment: Apparently the rake task you're calling writes to STDERR, not STDOUT. `&>` redirects *both* STDERR and STDOUT while `>` redirects only STDOUT. For more info see [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21).